# How to remove the top and bottom padding which gets automatically created in div tags

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have a Div like this

```
<div align="center">
    <p style="color: black; font-size: 10px;"><b>Summary</b></p>
</div>
```

And when i use this div the it shows me summary but with added padding on both top and bottom when i use it in jquery mobile.. How to remove this padding?

Comment: div{ padding:0; } in your css

Comment: what if i want to specify the padding to be removed from a particular div?

Comment: give this div an id like id="myID" and call in your css #myID{ padding:0; }

Comment: @QQping nope it didnt go..Is it padding only or something else?

Comment: just edited my answer depending on your comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have multiple ways to disable the padding in a div.
first one is to define the element style

`<div style="padding: 0;">...</div>`

second one (and much prettier) is to define an ID in your div like

`<div id="myID">...</div>`

and set in your css the padding values to zero like this:

`#myID{ padding:0; }`

If it isn't padding, you can try `margin: 0;` too.

Most of html elements have by default margin and padding. to disable this put the following part on top of your .css file:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi QQping its still not working... Maybe we need to wrap the content or so?

Comment: can you maybe provide a screenshot and a bit more code? does your div inherit the padding from a parent element?

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the content UI element and any div that is dynamically sized, the automatic margins are generated by the content tag in jQuery mobile. Add this to your CSS:

```
.ui-content {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```